# How to convert date to string in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, unix-timestamp

i need some help to convert date into a string

i have an sql database running on my unix box which stores the date in str eg:1371509465

i would like to run a query to find if any future dates exist in the database

is there an equivalent function to php's strtotime in shell ?

Comment: "php's strtotime in shell" in Google brings some results, have a glance at it

Comment: Just to confirm, you are talking about the time-stamp, right?  Because a date already _is_ a string. ^^

Comment: yes a command in shell to convert  Mon, 17 Jun 2013 22:51:05 GMT to 1371509465... i looked at strtotime but that doesnt help as I need something similar in shell

Comment: You mean like `date +%s`?

Comment: yes but when i execute that command i get %s as output. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: someone has posted date -d "2011/11/25 10:00:00" "+%s" to convert it to timestamp however when i paste this in my shell i get an error date: illegal option -- d

Comment: What shell are you using? And do you know what version of `date`?

Comment: ive tried korn shell and bash shell and both give me the same output. how would i find the version of date ?

Comment: Since you appear to have a PHP solution, why not call PHP from the shell?

Answer (score 3):

Linux:

```
date --date='@1371509465'
```

Mac OS/X:

```
date -r 1371509465
```

perl:

```
perl -e "print scalar localtime(1371509465);"
```

Comment: I think i found the answer is to have GNU core utilities installed. is there any other way to convert it to timestamp without having to install core utilities ??

Comment: I don't know about SunOS.  Do you have Perl installed?  Or another language?

Comment: I do know about SunOS: up to v 5.10 (solaris 10) - use perl or install GNU coreutils. Solaris 11 has GNU coreutils as a package. IT may already be there.

Answer (score 1):

found a way of doing that on solaris date

truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | grep time | awk -F" = " '{print $3}'